# Корзина на php, как уникализировать товары в сессиях?

Tags: php, корзина

Как сделать так, чтобы в корзину попадали позиции по-отдельности? Сейчас при добавлении первого товара всё в порядке, а при добавлении другого позиция не добавляется, а перезаписывается. В корзине постоянно один товар с меняющимся названием. Данные корзины храню в сессиях.

Обработчик:

```
$item_id = $_POST['id'];
$qty = $_SESSION['$item_id'][1] + $_POST['qty'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ foreach($result as $row){ $product_name = $row["name"]; } } else { echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

$_SESSION['$item_id'] = [$product_name, $qty];
```

Вывод:

```
$product_name = $_SESSION['$item_id'][0];
$qty = $_SESSION['$item_id'][1];

<? foreach($_SESSION['$item_id'] AS $value) {?>
<td class="uk-text-nowrap"><?echo $value?></td>
<?}?>
```

Comment: Читать содержимое сессии, прибавлять к нему новое значение, и перезаписывать значение в сессии. То есть в сессии будет хранится строка вида '25,68,56'  при добавлении продукта с ид 111 нужно прибавить к переменной сессии ",111". При обработке товаров исспользовать implode

Comment: ```$_SESSION[$item_id]```  А что тут делают кавычки? Уберите как в моем примере.
Далее.... ```foreach($_SESSION as $item){foreach ($item as $value){/*ваш код вывода*/}}...```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример как это хранить в сессии, код скопирован из вопроса и исправлен только в части работы с сессией, с базой работать как в этом примере - нельзя!.

Обработчик:

```
$item_id = $_POST['id'];
$qty = $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['qty'] + $_POST['qty'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='$item_id'";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){    //а это точно работает как вы ожидаете? 
  foreach($result as $row){          //и эта строка под сомнением
    $product_name = $row["name"]; 
  }
} else { 
  echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;
}

$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id] = ['name' => $product_name, 'qty' => $qty];
```

Вывод:

```
$product_name = $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['name'];
$qty = $_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]['qty'];

foreach($_SESSION['cart'] AS $item) {
  //возможно здесь нужно добавить echo "<tr>";
  foreach($item as $value){
    echo "<td class='uk-text-nowrap'>$value</td>";
  };
  //возможно здесь нужно добавить echo "</tr>";
};
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: Извините, ещё такой вопрос, я добавил в сессию ещё и product id, Чтобы по нему удалять товары из корзины. Как правильно сделать удаление? В обработчик я передаю этот id из сессии? В самом обработчике: `$item_id = $_POST['item_id']; unset($_SESSION['cart'][$item_id]);` ?

Comment: Да, именно так делать удаление. еще вам может пригодиться такая конструкция ```foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item_id => $item) { //в $item_id - будет id вашего товара, а в $item - данные(имя, количество)}```